# Adding parenthesis to a number that is binding

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

My `label` is bound to a number and for example shows **72** so that "72" is coming directly from binding and I can show it in label fine But I want to wrap it around parenthesis so would show as **(72)** 
I know I can use `StringFormat` but I tried and couldn't quite get the syntax right. Would you help me show how it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a `Label`, you'll need to use `ContentStringFormat` instead

```
<Label ContentStringFormat="{}({0})" Content={Binding MyNumberProperty} />
```

Comment: Would you mind to explain the `{}` at the beginning of the format string?

Comment: {} is used to escape the string.. Though, now that I think about it, it should only be needed if a curly brace is the first character in the string format. Try removing it, it should work as well.